# Ignite show out of Heap memory exception

Tags: spring-boot, ignite, apacheignite

I am running my services on ignite and I have one ignite server node. After running my services for several days my ignite show out of heap memory error . and I don't have any idea about it how to resolve this or what may be the possible reason of this.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are running out of space. Take a look at the [metrics configuration](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring-metrics/intro), precisely at your [data region](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring-metrics/new-metrics#data-region-io) metrics.

Check [this](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/memory-configuration/eviction-policies) docs on how to enable eviction, or consider turning on native persistence.